# 176. Second Highest Salary for this leetcode 7/9 testcase only passed

Tags: sql, mysql

176. Second Highest Salary
     Attempted
     Medium
     Topics
     Companies
     SQL Schema
     Pandas Schema

Table: Employee

| Column Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| salary | int |

id is the primary key (column with unique values) for this table.
Each row of this table contains information about the salary of an employee.

Write a solution to find the second highest salary from the Employee table. If there is no second highest salary, return null (return None in Pandas).

The result format is in the following example.

Example 1:

Input:
Employee table:

| id | salary |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 300 |

Output:

| SecondHighestSalary |
| --- |
| 200 |

Example 2:

Input:
Employee table:

| id | salary |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |

Output:

| SecondHighestSalary |
| --- |
| null |

And My solution is ::::::

Mysql :

```
select IFNULL(
    (select salary
    from Employee
    Order by salary desc
    Limit 1,1), null
) as SecondHighestSalary
```

I am passing only 7/9 test cases Tell me why didn't it work

Comment: What does your solution do if there are two or more employees with the same highest salary?

Comment: I think you should group by salary because there can be two or more equal salaries, try it

Comment: You can also make use of the `DENSE_RANK()` window function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach. It checks that the salary in current row is smaller than the maximum salary.

```sql
SELECT MAX(salary) AS SecondHighestSalary
FROM Employee
WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee);
```